# Что делает data['Цена'] = re.findall?

Tags: python-3.x

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, что делает `data['Цена'] = re.findall`?

```py
try:
    data['Цена'] = re.findall('productPriceLocal":"([0-9]{1,})',r.text)[0]
except:
    try:
        data['Цена'] = ''.join(tree.cssselect('detail-price-uah')[0].itertext())
    except Exception as msg:
        print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re` - модуль для работы с регулярными выражениями в Python.

`re.findall()` - это функция, которая возвращает все совпадения с некоторым шаблоном.

Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> re.**findall**(*pattern, string, flags=0*)
>   Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of *pattern* in *string*, as a list of strings. The *string* is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
>   one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group. Empty matches are included in the result.
>
> *Changed in version 3.7:* Non-empty matches can now start just after a
>   previous empty match.

В вашем случае вернётся первое совпадение с шаблоном `'productPriceLocal":"([0-9]{1,})'`

Подробнее прочитать о регулярных выражениях можете [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/).